# Not able to register the app in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to register an app in sharepoint using the appregnew form. I am giving all the details especially domain name as *companyname.onmicrosoft.com* and request URI as *https://companyname.sharepoint.com/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx*. When I click on the create button it is showing me the error message as **An unexpected error has occurred**.
Could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is your app domain the same as your sharepoint domain? We think the app domain should be a different domain. Here is the tutorial about how to register add-in:

- [To register by using AppRegNew.aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins#to-register-by-using-appregnewaspx)

BR

Comment: Thanks...I was referring to the link to register. My app domain name is companyname.onmicrosoft.com. So I should be giving companyname.onmicrosoft at App Domain?